# Why spark driver program do not use swap?

Tags: apache-spark

My spark driver program will throw OutOfMemory error. When I check the memory usage, the whole swap are maintain unused.

Why spark not using swap if the memory is not enough?  Is there some lock setting to lock the memory in RAM on purpose ?

Comment: I am not sure what you have written  but check this link for Memory Management in spark. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management

Comment: Actually it is forcely recommended to deactivate the swap usage on OS level when using any big data system (to name some, hadoop, cassandra, spark ...etc). Activating Swap will decrease the performance, as the application will do some I/O operations instead of just retrieving/saving data from/to memory